# Use of unresolved identifier "Form"

Tags: swift, swiftui

I've been trying to replicate Apple WWDC 19 example below - converting a SwiftUI `VStack` into a `Form` - to no avail.

Here's the video mentioning `Form`:

https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/216/  (`34:08`)

Here is the code I am using for VStack:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView : View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Toggle(isOn: .constant(true)) {
                Text("Toggle")
            }
            Stepper(value:.constant(4), in: 1...10) {
                Text("Stepper")
            }
            Text("Hello World")
        }
    }
}

#if DEBUG
struct ContentView_Previews : PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
#endif
```

And here is the code I am using for `Form`:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView : View {
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Toggle(isOn: .constant(true)) {
                Text("Toggle")
            }
            Stepper(value:.constant(4), in:1...10) {
               Text("Stepper")
            }
            Text("Hello World")
        }
    }
}

#if DEBUG
struct ContentView_Previews : PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
#endif
```

The error I'm getting in the last snippet:

> Use of unresolved identifier 'Form'

Comment: I also met this. Looks like the Form doesn't exist yet in beta XCode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beta 2 has introduced form.

The difference to `List` is that it can not be initialized with a data collection.

```swift
public struct Form<Content> where Content : View {

    public init(content: () -> Content)

    public var body: _View { get }

    /// The type of view representing the body of this view.
    ///
    /// When you create a custom view, Swift infers this type from your
    /// implementation of the required `body` property.
    public typealias Body
}
```

Answer (score 6):

<s>It seems like `Form` is not part of SwiftUI yet (?).</s>

But you can use a grouped list to achieve the same result.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
        List {
            Section(header: Text("Section").font(.largeTitle)) {
                Text("Text")
                Toggle(isOn: .constant(true)) { Text("Toggle") }
            }
        }.listStyle(.grouped)
    }

}
```

---

It is available as of `Beta 2`.

Your code...

```swift
struct ContentView : View {
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Toggle(isOn: .constant(true)) {
                Text("Toggle")
            }
            Stepper(value:.constant(4), in:1...10) {
                Text("Stepper")
            }
            Text("Hello World")
        }
    }
}
```

...produces this output:

[image]

Comment: Awesome, good solution for now. Didn't know that. Thanks Matteo!